# Downloaded .apk file in Android corrupted

Tags: android, download, corrupt-data

I need to download by program an .apk file then launching its activity.
The code I am using is the following

```
private String downloadFile(String sourceURL, String destinationPath)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sourceURL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) > 0) {
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
```

// EDITED here: Make the file rw, otherwise the apk file will not be installed
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 666 " + destinationPath);

```
            message = "OK";
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            message = "Malformed URL error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
        catch (ProtocolException e) {
            message = "Protocol exception error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            message = "File not found error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
        catch (IOException e)   {
            e.printStackTrace();
            message = "Failed to download the file : " + e.getMessage();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

I mention that I call the method first for a text file, then for an apk file. Each time I process the files locally, therefore, somehow I know what's going wrong or not. In this way I know that the text file is downloaded correctly. But the .apk file is corrupted. Because I develop locally, with access to DDMS and localhost (the IP: 10.0.2.2) I can firmly state that the culprit is the code above. When I artificially replace the 'downloaded' file, through DDMS, with the original .apk file, all processing that follows is Ok. In addition, I have byes difference when I compare the original and the downloaded .apk files.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
PS: Searching, I realized that, while is a popular issue, there is no consistent answer to it. In my case I identified it as purely a download method issue.

Comment: Is the server sending the APK as binary? What is the value of the Content-Type header?

Comment: Interesting. You suggest to setRequestProperty to binary? If so, what would be the right parameter (because it seems to be rather application format oriented).Something like connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "multipart/form-data") ?

Comment: What is the type of sourceURL? Is it an HTTP request? Where are you downloading the file from? You would have to set the Content-Type header in the server code.

Comment: I am downloading an apk file. The first question would then be "is this a binary format?" I remind that the above code works fine, as it is, for text files. Then as you can see, I don't use HttpURLConnection, but URLConnection. By what I've read the use of one or another depends on the SDK version, but I'm using in the manifest a target 15 and minimum 8. Still playing with options ...

Comment: "I am downloading an apk file" - from where? "above code works fine, as it is, for text files" - text files can be downloaded as text encoded, but apk files need to be binary encoded.

Comment: I download it from my hosted server, not from the market. What would be the header for the apk file to set the "content-type"? The problem I'm having is that the download is executed, the number of bytes is the right one, only that it is corrupted because, I suppose, I don't correctly set the content type

Comment: You need to configure your server to set the correct MIME type for the apk. Depending on your server, you will find the information on the internet to do that. The MIME type for APK is `application/vnd.android.package-archive`.

Comment: The server is configured correctly (mime.type and mime.conf), the MIME type is the one you posted, still get file corrupted.

Comment: Thanks Raja, your comments conforted my current solution search, I'll update the post when I'll find the clean one, I think I have all elements in place to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see above the answer under the EDITED line. Implemented, works fine, that may help others